# unable to install Ubuntu 16.04, ignores USB boot order and goes to Win 10

Tags: boot, usb

Trying to install Ubuntu on an Acer Cloudbook and it seems to ignore the boot order (changed to USB HDD first) and goes right to Windows 10. This is going to be a clean install because these cloudbooks only have 16 GB hard drives which really means 14 GB. I am unable to update with the Creators update 1709 because the hard drive is too small and it won't allow me to use an SD card to store enough of the update files. I want to completely remove Windows 10 and format the drive during the Ubuntu install but I never get any kind of Ubuntu screen to make that choice. I have also disabled fast startup. 
The USB I am using to load Ubuntu on is a pre-loaded USB I purchased direct from Ubuntu. I checked on another computer and all the files seem to be there.

I have deleted everything possible from Windows 10 and the only programs I have added are Chrome and VLC.

It offers the option to change to legacy mode but I haven't tried it. I will do so tomorrow. I did several clean installs of Windows 10 before trying to get it down to fit on the drive, what does Legacy mode do?

Comment: Can you get into BIOS and change from UEFI to Legacy mode? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1010114/edit) your question above and add the new information.

Comment: See https://phoenixts.com/blog/uefi-vs-legacy-bios/

Comment: You are welcome. I have converted the comments to an answer. Please accept the answer by putting a green check mark in its left margin. This will help others.

Answer (score 1):

## For a clean install of Ubuntu erasing Windows and all the data

**Background**

Modern computers use Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI), a basic system that allows the operating system communicate with the hardware. This work used to be done by Basic Input Ouput System (BIOS). We still use the word BIOS and UEFI interchangeably.

In this case, something in the UEFI of the Acer Cloudbook ignores boot order and prevents booting from the USB.

**The Solution**

1. Go into BIOS (the UEFI) settings and look for a setting that toggles
   between UEFI and Legacy BIOS modes.
2. Switch to Legacy BIOS mode.
3. Change boot order to boot from USB first, followed by the internal
   SSD.
4. Save and exit UEFI settings.

In a dual-boot system this change will prevent pre-installed Windows from booting, as it was installed in the UEFI mode. This is not an issue in this case, where Ubuntu will be the only OS.

Reference: https://phoenixts.com/blog/uefi-vs-legacy-bios/

Hope this helps

Comment: Great answer, solves my problem.